# How to define a Returning parameter?

Tags: java, methods, return, abap

I get used to JAVA, thus having problem to write this code in ABAP.

I call a method with two parameters. It should return a number, so I can save it.

What I want is

```
int result = generate_num(40,5);

int generate_num(int thisNum, int newDigit){
    return thisNum * 10 + newDigit;
}
```

In ABAP I tried this so far.

//Declared Method

```
methods GENERATE_NUM
importing
  !thisNum type I
  !NEWDIGIT type DIGIT_NUMBER_VALUE.
```

//Calling Method

```
CALL METHOD me->Generate_NUM
   EXPORTING
       thisNUm = 40
       newDigit = 5.
```

//Method itself

```
METHOD GENERATE_NUM.

  
DATA: newNum type i.

  If thisnum < 0.
    newNum = thisnum * 10 - newdigit.
  Else.
    newNum = thisnum * 10 + newdigit.
  ENDIF.

  RETURNING VALUE(newNum).   

ENDMETHOD.
```

But I get lost in this code, have no idea how to return a value and how to save it in another variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's how you declare a method with a return parameter:

```
METHODS generate_num 
  IMPORTING
    thisNum TYPE i   
    newdigit TYPE digit_number_value
  RETURNING
    value(result) TYPE i.
```

Note that a method can only have one `RETURNING` parameter, and that parameter must always be passed by value.

In the method implementation, you set the return value by modifying the local variable you declared as returning parameter:

```
METHOD generate_num.

  IF thisnum < 0.
    result = thisnum * 10 - newdigit.
  ELSE.
    result = thisnum * 10 + newdigit.
  ENDIF.     

ENDMETHOD.
```

The returned value will be whatever value `result` has when the method returns. Just like with `EXPORTING` parameters.

When you call a method you can either use the classic CALL syntax which is more like the syntax seasoned ABAP developers are used to:

```
DATA lv_foo TYPE i. " the variable you want to store the return value in

CALL METHOD me->generate_num
   EXPORTING
       thisNUm = 40
       newDigit = 5
   RECEIVING
       result = lv_foo.
```

or the functional syntax which is more like the Java syntax you might be used to:

```
lv_foo = me->generate_num( thisNUm = 40 newDigit = 5).
```

If the method doesn't just have importing parameters but also changing or exporting parameters, the syntax looks like this:

```
lv_foo = me->generate_num( 
   EXPORTING thisNUm = 40 
             newDigit = 5
   CHANGING cv_bar = lv_bar ).
```

Comment: in the declaring section can I just write (result) type I? 
Because It displays "(RESULT)" is not expected.

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake. There must not be a space between VALUE and the paranthesis. I corrected it in my answer. The VALUE is not optional. You have to declare for all parameters if they are passed by-value (VALUE keyword and paranthesis) or by-reference (no VALUE and no paranthesis or REFERENCE and paranthesis). by-reference is not allowed for returning parameters, so you must declare them as by-value.

Comment: Your last sentence is not correct.  Yes, you need a returning parameter if you want to set a variable to the result of a method, but you can put IMPORTING EXPORTING CHANGING between the parentheses without using the keywords CALL METHOD.  ex: lcl_routines=>method( EXPORTING imp = 'testing' IMPORTING exp = l_string ).

Comment: @Bryan Cain: Thank you for that correction. I mentioned it in the answer.

Comment: Sometimes writing ABAP code without the help of transaction (in this case SE37) can be confusing and led to typos and other mistakes. It's a good idea to write functions/classes/method with the help of transactions and then how code is generated behind the scene. You would have seen easily the returning value(xxx) in the method header.

Comment: I wrote that answer from home and corrected it when I was back at work where I have access to our SAP systems.